# undefined reference to `iluInit' ONLY

Tags: c++, devil

This is very strange or very simple. I am using Devil library and in the very simple program I have to initialize it by:

```
ilInit();
iluInit();
```

And here is the problem. `IlInit()` works fine, but `iluInit()` is not! It can not find the reference.

Of course I include headers:

```
#include <IL/il.h>
#include <IL/ilu.h>
```

And compile my file by:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -O3 myIL.cpp -lglfw3 -lGL -lGLEW -lIL -lGLU -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lpthread -lXrandr -lXi -o myIL
```

(generally I want to use Devil lib for OpenGL project but I don't think it is important right now).

I have also all headers in `/usr/include/IL` and *.a, *.so etc. files in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

Btw it also be great if someone could explain me what the difference between `IlInit()`, `iluInit()` and `ilutInit()`. I cannot find the simple explanation.

Comment: Three different libraries, DevIL, ILU and ILUT.  Who the heck comes up with names like that :(  Doesn't look like you are linking any of them.

Comment: Isn't this `-lIL` for linking library(ies)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about devils, but I suspect you forgot to link against the relevant library -- wouldn't that be `libILU.so`, i.e. require the compiler/loader option `-lILU`?

Comment: Yes, I thought so that it will be very easy.... The same is when you want to use `ilutInit()` you have to include `#include <IL/ilut.h>` AND add `-lILUT`. Thanks a lot!!